# How to prevent IntegrityError in a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning django and I follow this blog project on codemy youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ph8GF84fX4&ab_channel=Codemy.comCodemy.com
And I wanted to improve my code with ForeignKey but I got stuck.

I want to add a Category into my Post model. So I used the ForeignKey. Not every post has a categroy since I added this model just recently, but I used the default argument in the Category class, which should solve this problem. However, trying several options, I cannot migrate my models and run the server again.

My code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="uncategorized")

    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse("blog")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30000)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse("post", args = [str(self.id)])
```

**The error:**
**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'blog_post' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: blog_post.category_id contains a value 'uncategorized' that does not have a corresponding value in blog_category.id.**

I have used the category in my forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Post
    fields = ["title", "author", "category", "body"]
    widgets = {
        "title": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "author": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "category": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "body": forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    }
```

which is used in my views:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from . import models
from.forms import PostForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy



class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "post_list.html"
    #ordering = ["-id"]

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = models.Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "add_post.html"
    #fields = ["title", "author", "body"]

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "update_post.html"
    #fields = ["title", "body"]

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = "delete_post.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blog")
```

Comment: can you post your views?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, so it shows more code. I am not sure whether it helps for orientation.... According to the error sentence, I believe the problem is in the model...
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: can you delete migrations files and remigrate once

Comment: ok, this moved me slightly forward, I can run the server. However, whenever I need for the page the Post model I get: table blog_post has no column named category_id

Comment: which view are you running in url?

Comment: I guess you are running add post view you will need to catch exception Integrity error from where the request is coming and send response as bad request

Comment: Not even my PostListView is running

Comment: which url are view are you sending and you got the error?

Comment: I get the same error even when I want to see the posts in the admin environemnt

Comment: My IndexView is running and AddPostView is running. The others get the same error

Comment: After deleting the whole database I was successful with the totally same code... I have no idea what was wrong, but it works now.

Comment: Your database seems to have issue